# Speed up the run time of calculation that reads data from all previous days in a nested loop

Tags: excel, vba

I'm computing the Lifo Stack on every day since a select start date.

Every day the code processes the data from the days before and outputs a lifo stack. The data set has a lot of cells and the output is almost 700,000  units of data and takes ten minutes to output.
There is new data every day and a new stack needs to be created. If I repeat the code every day it takes too long.

How could I can either make the current code more efficient or add the data from the new dates to the stack by only looking at the previous day's stack (since that is the only stack that matters when adding a new day's data and stack)?

```vb
Option Explicit

Dim myStack() As Variant
Dim pricesStacked() As Variant
Dim stackCount As Long

Sub IncrementEndRow()
    Dim endRow As Long
    Dim startRow As Long
    Dim LR As Long
    LR = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)
    
    startRow = 1
    
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Output").UsedRange.Clear
    For endRow = 2 To 5000
        ProcessDataWithStack startRow, endRow
    Next endRow
End Sub


Sub ProcessDataWithStack(startRow As Long, endRow As Long)
    Dim dataColumn As Range
    Dim priceColumn As Range
    Dim dateColumn As Range
    Dim dataArr As Variant
    Dim priceArr As Variant
    Dim dateArr As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim outputSheet As Worksheet
    Dim outputRange As Range
    Dim outputRow As Long
    outputRow = 1
    
    Set outputSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Output")

    Set dataColumn = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & startRow & ":C" & endRow)
    Set priceColumn = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & startRow & ":B" & endRow)
    Set dateColumn = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & startRow & ":B" & endRow)

    dataArr = dataColumn.Value
    priceArr = priceColumn.Value
    dateArr = dateColumn.Value

    ReDim myStack(1 To dataColumn.Rows.Count)
    ReDim pricesStacked(1 To dataColumn.Rows.Count)
    stackCount = 0

    For i = LBound(dataArr, 1) To UBound(dataArr, 1)
        Dim dataValue As Variant
        Dim priceValue As Variant
        Dim dateValue As Variant

        dataValue = dataArr(i, 1)
        priceValue = priceArr(i, 1)
        dateValue = dateArr(endRow, 1)

        If dataValue > 0 Then
            stackCount = stackCount + 1
            myStack(stackCount) = dataValue
            pricesStacked(stackCount) = priceValue
        Else
            While stackCount > 0 And myStack(stackCount) + dataValue < 0
                dataValue = dataValue + myStack(stackCount)
                stackCount = stackCount - 1
            Wend

            If stackCount > 0 Then
                myStack(stackCount) = myStack(stackCount) + dataValue
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    
    outputRow = FindNextAvailableRow(outputSheet)
    
    For i = 1 To stackCount
        outputSheet.Cells(outputRow + i - 1, 1).Value = myStack(i)
        outputSheet.Cells(outputRow + i - 1, 2).Value = pricesStacked(i)
        outputSheet.Cells(outputRow + i - 1, 3).Value = dateValue
    Next i
End Sub


Function FindNextAvailableRow(sheet As Worksheet) As Long
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = sheet.Cells(sheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    FindNextAvailableRow = lastRow + 1
End Function
```

I think if I kept all the data up to today fixed and computed the stack without the initial for loop and kept incrementing the range each day it would only calculate one stack.

Comment: What is preventing you from trying your idea?

Comment: When making a large number of worksheet changes, turn off `Application.ScreenUpdating` and `Application.Calculation`. Every time you put a new value into the sheet, the application wastes time by checking if any formulas need to update or if any visible windows need to be refreshed. Just make sure to change them back to `True` and `xlCalculationAutomatic` at the end.

Comment: Alternatively, if you arrange the output data in a 2D array, it can be done in a single step, which is very fast. `myRange.Resize(UBound(myArr,1)-LBound(myArr,1)+1, UBound(myArr,2)-LBound(myArr,2)+1).Value = myArr`

Comment: Or for your 1D arrays eg - `outputSheet.Cells(outputRow, 1).Resize(stackCount).Value = Application.Transpose(myStack)`

Comment: @toddleson so for the 2D array what line should i replace with the line you suggested

Answer (score 0):

I see, you understand that the number of data transfers between Excel and VBA has to be minimized by reading as many cells at the same time as possible, as in your code: `dataArr = dataColumn.Value`.

However, the other direction, writing back data to Excel is also expensive, so instead of your loop `For i = 1 To stackCount`, I would update the value of a bigger `Range`, like this:

```
    ' ...
    outputRow = FindNextAvailableRow(outputSheet)
    
    outputSheet.Cells(outputRow, 1).Resize(stackCount, 1).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(myStack)
    outputSheet.Cells(outputRow, 1).Resize(stackCount, 2).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(pricesStacked)
    outputSheet.Cells(outputRow, 1).Resize(stackCount, 3).Value = dateValue
End Sub
```

**Update**

Corrected the orientation of the arrays as Tim Williams suggested.

Comment: @TimWilliams: Right, I forgat about that.